# Is there any way to force the Linux kernel to ignore O_DIRECT?

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel

Without going into a lot of detail about *why* I want to do this ... is there any way to force modern Linux kernels to ignore the `O_DIRECT` flag when opening a file?  Basically, I want `O_DIRECT` treated as a no-op, in which the application is free to specify it, but the kernel simply treats it as if it was not specified.

I've seen various other questions on Stack Exchange and elsewhere that ask similar things, but I haven't been able to find any information about this exact requirement.  Is there any `sysctl` or anything I can set that would produce this effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't any sysctl or alike for that.

You should use a LD_PRELOAD hack to override the openat() function.